# wsl-2 bash: /mnt/c/ruby26-x64/bin/rails: ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, wsl-2

I've been happily running rails projects inside WSL2 for a couple of years, then soon after upgrading to Rails 6.1.7 I couldn't run Rails at all, nor Bundler, nor ruby, nor gem. The command line error was:

> bash: /mnt/c/ruby26-x64/bin/rails: ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Linux appeared to be trying to run ruby version 2.6 installed on my windows C drive (C:\Ruby26-x64) istead of ruby 2.7 via rvm. That clearly will not work. The "bad interpreter" issue can arise from windows system line endings, so looks consistent with this.

Answer (score 0):

By following advice in rvm.io, this solved the issue:

1. Update rvm to latest:

> $ rvm get stable

This upgraded rvm 1.29.10 to rvm 1.29.12

2. Add a .ruby-version file with contents: ruby-2.7
3. In windows shell: wsl --shutdown
4. Restart wsl and retry.

At this point the issue was fixed on one PC but the issue with rails remains on another pc, however bundler and gem were now working. The additional step to resolve this on the other PC was:

5. $ bundle install.

This fetched and installed everything in the gemfile. Running Rails s now worked.